# Laravel 5.6 npm bootstrap 4 error

Tags: laravel, npm, bootstrap-4

I'm upgrading Bootstrap-scss 3.7.7 to Bootstrap 4.0.0, after uninstalling Bootstrap-scss 3.7.7 and then trying to install Bootstrap-scss  4.0.0 I get this error:

```
 at options.error (C:\wamp64\www\QuizApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
status: 1,
file: 'C:/wamp64/www/QuizApp/resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
line: 9,
column: 1,
message: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\app.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss.\n        on line 9 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss"; \n
^\n',
formatted: 'Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss.\n        on line 9 of
resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss"; \n   ^\n',
 messageFormatted: '\u001b[4mresources\\assets\\sass\\app.scss\u001b[24m\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss.\n        on line 9 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss"; \n   ^\n',
messageOriginal: 'File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss.',
relativePath: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\app.scss',
name: 'Error',
stack: 'Error: resources\\assets\\sass\\app.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss.\n        on line 9 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
\n   ^\n\n    at options.error (C:\\wamp64\\www\\QuizApp\\node_modules\\node-sass\\lib\\index.js:291:26)',
showStack: false,
showProperties: true,
plugin: 'gulp-sass' }


App.scss line 9

@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
```

Comment: what "uninstalled bootstrap-scss 3.7.7 to bootstrap 4.0.0"? It is not clear, what you wanna say?

Comment: Im sorry. i'm uninstalled bootstrap 3.7.7 and trying to install bootstrap 4.0.0

Comment: you should use relative path like `@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";`

Comment: same error i updated my question for more information

Comment: just open up the node_modules folder and track for the bootstrap path and set relative path with `~`.

Comment: path is like node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss . is that correct?

Comment: OK you're loading stylesheet in `index.js`, so your path should be like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss">`